# Amazon Workspace Client not connecting to Amazon Workspace on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: aws

Download from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Install using command

```
sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: More details are needed. What command or app is being used? What error message are you seeing?